# What is primary reason for a matter to be transparent as Cornea is?

Tags: optics

Is it because its internal structure is Crystalline? I mean by transparency [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28optics%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [Cornea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornea) is mostly fibrous - not crystalline.

As for the physics of optical transparency - [here's](http://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2046) an elementary introduction

> In order to go through a material evenly, light has to avoid two things:
>
> 1. being absorbed
> 2. being scattered off into another direction.

See also

- [Why glass is transparent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/why-glass-is-transparent)
- [Why is air invisible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1836/12613)
- [How can a body be transparent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30210/12613)
- [Why is the atmosphere transparent in the visible spectrum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29197/12613)
- [Why does paper become translucent when smeared with oil but not (so much) with water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30365/12613)
- [Why do wet objects become darker?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30366/why-wet-is-dark)
- [Transparency of materials](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11138/transparency-of-materials)
- [Why isn't light scattered through transparency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/why-isnt-light-scattered-through-transparency)

Comment: I found out inspiring teaching on transparency of glass and why it is transparent for some frequencies( light). -http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Omr0JNyDBI0